# Tkinter: Why am I not able to run a code by double-clicking the file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

The code below runs properly, both by running on terminal and upon double-clicking the python file :

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
im_fr = Label(root)
im_fr.pack(expand = "yes")
root.mainloop()
```

But, the moment I use `PhotoImage` for displaying an image, it ceases to run by double clicking the file, nothing happens on a double-click. It runs only through terminal. The code is below:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
img = PhotoImage(file='img.png')
im_fr = Label(root, image = img)
im_fr.pack(expand = "yes")
root.mainloop() 

#Runs well on terminal -> python fi.py
#Doesn't run on double-click, nothing happens
```

All other Python files run well upon being double-clicked, it's just this one which refuses to.
Using python 2.7 on Mint 18.3.

Comment: are you using windows?

Comment: No, Linux Mint 18.3

Comment: try logging in as a root user and double clicking on it

Comment: @BlooB : Same result with `root` as well, it doesn't run. Other files, in the same folder, are responding well to double-click.

Comment: `img.png` is a relative path. That's probably why it fails when you double click. Use an absolute path to the image.

Comment: @jordanm: Thank you, it works!! I used the absolute path as you suggested. You could post it as an answer, I'll accept it.